# Is there any way to look for an image using the path? MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails (Android)

Tags: android, image, path, mediastore

I'm using  `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` in order to show the images the user have. But i'm not able to get an image through its path. 
Is there any way to look for an image using the path?

```
String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};  
String selection =  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like '%path%'";  //this doesn't work  
cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                       proj, // Which columns to return   
                       selection,       // WHERE clause;   
                       null,        
                       null); // Order-by clause
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED

Hi,

```
//I just get Image ID.

String [] proj={MediaStore.Image.Media._ID,MediaStore.Image.Media.DATA}
cursor=manageQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA+"= ' "+path+" ' ",null,null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

// and then, use ID to get thumbnails

Bitmap b=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr,Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)),kind, null);

// or for video

Bitmap b=MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)),kind, null);
```

BR,
Jett

Comment: I don't know, i've just tried with 
MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " =\"/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20100812_12342.jpg\""

but it doesn't find anything

Comment: Thanks!! I was searching into MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails, that's why it didn't find anything

Comment: For those having trouble with this, remove the spaces in the path of the WHERE clause...