# how to display images from a particular directory, android

Tags: android

In my gallery I have 3 directories. sahoo is one of the directory. I have different images in all three directories. But I want to show images of sahoo directory only. My program shows all images which is present in gallery. But I want to get images from sahoo directory only. How to do that?
I am using android.

Thanks
Deepak

I have used the following code

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
```

and in getview method i have written following lines of code

```
mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Log.e(TAG,"the position is"+position);
        long id = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
//      Log.e(TAG,"the value of id= "+id);
        //create the Uri for the Image 
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id+"");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setData(uri); 

        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is your sahoo directory a subdirectory of the gallery?

Comment: does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490623/is-there-any-way-to-look-for-an-image-using-the-path-mediastore-images-thumbnail

Comment: yes it works. sahoo directory is a subdirectory of gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get path of all images from using cursor. then check if the path does not match with the path of for which you donot want to show images then store the pathin arraylist. create your owngrid and adapter show image in ImageView using setImageURI() method. Donot use default gallery in this case.

```
uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };

            cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
String absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Thanks 
Sunil